# Resetting a password via a form and a unique code

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I have a small scale application that allows the admins to reset their password. I currently have it so that the admin will enter their email address and it generates a random key and emails it to them. The random key is also stored in the database for the user. The email also includes a link to a form where the user can reset their password by entering their username and the code that was sent to them.

Below is the reset password form:

```
<h1>Reset Your Password</h1>

<form id="reset" name="reset" method="post" action="reset-admin-password-exec.php">
<table width="365" height="147" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="144">Username: </td>
    <td><input name="username" type="text" class="textfield" id="username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code: </td>
    <td><input name="code" type="text" class="textfield" id="code" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>New Password: </td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="code" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Confirm Password: </td>
    <td><input name="cpassword" type="password" class="textfield" id="cpassword" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Reset" /></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here is the reset-admin-password-exec.php file that processes the code:

```
<?
    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;


    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //check for validation errors
    if (isset ($_POST['username']) && !empty ($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    } else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'username do not match';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    if (isset ($_POST['code']) && !empty ($_POST['code'])) {
    $code = clean($_POST['code']);
    } else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'code do not match';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    if (isset ($_POST['password']) && !empty ($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    } else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'first do not match';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    if (isset ($_POST['cpassword']) && !empty ($_POST['cpassword'])) {
    $cpassword = clean($_POST['cpassword']);
    } else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'second do not match';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //Check that both password match
    if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';
        $errflag = true;    
    }


    //encrypt the password
    $salt1 = md5($username);
    $salt2 = md5(DB_PASSWORD);
    $password = sha1($salt1.$password.$salt2);


    //if there are input validations redirect back to main page
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: reset-admin-password-form.php");
        exit();
    }

    $qry = "        UPDATE  admins
                    SET password    =   '$password'
                    WHERE   randkey     =   '$code'
                                    AND     username        =       '$username'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    if($result) {
        echo $result;
        //header("location: reset-admin-password-success.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die(mysql_error());

    }

?>
```

All of my validations work and it will redirect if any fields are empty or if the passwords do not match. However, the query will still work if the `code` field does not match the `randkey` field in my table. I have tried putting `randkeys` as the field to ensure it fails, which it does.

When I echo out the `$qry` I get this: `UPDATE admins SET    password   =   'b978ac7c458d65ca31c02eb4e7dabd9aa6a8e235' WHERE    randkey  =  'CHLVQ6vfq' AND  username   =   'user.name'`

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Beware that the emailed code is password-equivalent and should also be hashed & salted.

Comment: Also, as stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: However, whilst you are using the ancient `mysql_*` extension, you should probably test [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) instead, as `mysql_query()` will succeed even if no rows are matched (there are no errors in the `UPDATE` command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the query is actually working? It may not be outputting any errors but that doesn't mean it's actually updating any rows.

Make use of [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php); this function will tell you if any rows were actually updated (i.e. if the `WHERE` clause matches)

You should change the last portion of your code to:

```
$rows = mysql_affected_rows();
if( $rows == 1 ) {
    header("location: reset-admin-password-success.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    if( $rows == 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('Your username and code do not match');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array('Unknown error');
    }
    session_write_close();
    header("location: reset-admin-password-form.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I replaced the last bit of code with what you suggested and it is still going through even without the correct code. I replaced the `header("location: reset-admin-password-success.php");` with `printf(mysql_affected_rows());` and got a `-1` as a result

Comment: So that means the query failed entirely. I don't see any syntax errors in the sample you pasted, are you sure the column names and everything are spelled correctly? Are you updating the right table (admins instead of users for example)? Have you created a MySQL connection and selected the correct database?